# Regarding parsing HTTPResponse returned from python 2.x in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4

I am new to Python. I have a code both in python 3.x & python 2.x (Actually, it is a library which has been written in 2.x). I am calling a function in python 2.x from python 3.x. The library return a HTTPResponse (from python 2.x). I am not able to parse the HTTPResponse in my code (In Python 3.x).

**My request is :**

```
jsonData = {'string': post_message_data['Message']}

url = "%s/testurl/" % (settings.STIX_API_URL)

response = requests.post(url, jsonData)
```

**Processing request in Python 2.x**

In python 2.x I am processing this request & sending back http response which is plain text reply parsed from email.

```
htmldata = request.body

strdata = json.loads(htmldata)
html =  strdata['string']

reply = quotations.extract_from(html, 'text/html')

reply = quotations.extract_from_html(html)

return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'reply':reply}), mimetype='application/json')
```

Now my question is "how to get that json data in json format in the function called in 3.x"

I have tried response.read() , response.readall() , response.content. Each time getting different errors.

Comment: Why not just write the whole code in one version? Should save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: What is the `HttpResponse` object here? Is this a Django object perhaps?

Comment: And why not just use `response.json()` instead of decoding the JSON response yourself?

Comment: It appears you are confused as to what the `requests` library is about; it is a 3rd party library that works on both Python 2 and 3. Don't try and treat it like the `urllib2` / `urllib.request` libraries that come with Python 2 and Python 3 respectively.

Comment: Hie Martijn, I am using Django framework & I also tried response.json() but it's raising some value error as "raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None". Frankly I am newbie to both python & Django. So not so clear about some concepts you said before.

Comment: Hello Kevin, Email parsing library I am using is in python2.7 thats why I need to use both in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem when I was sending JSON data from request. It was not in proper format. That's why in `HTTPResponse` object I was getting 500 Internal server error (No JSON can be decoded). I found this error when I checked response.content

After that I properly encoded the JSON and got correct output in JSON format from response object. Like Martijn said using `response.json()`.

Answer (score 0):

Versions of Python have *absolutely nothing* to do with this question.

The response you get from the `requests.post` call has a `json()` method which returns the content as a parsed Python data structure.

Comment: Hie Daniel, Do you want to say something like this

Comment: reply = json.dumps(response.json())

Comment: No, if I meant that I would have said it. Where would `response` come from there? Your problem as you described it is on the client side; that's where you need to access the json, surely?

Comment: Actually I am using library which is written in python2.7 That's why I am using both versions of python in one project.  The JSON data passed in request is html view of email reply. The email parsing library is in 2.7 to which I am posting a request. Its a mailguns talon library. After parsing html I am extracting only reply from html that is pure text & sending it back as JSON using : return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'reply':reply}))

Comment: Yes, that's what you said in the question. So where is your problem?

Comment: Problem is that, I am not getting the the way to get that reply from response object returned. I am totally newbie to this that is I think the cause of my problem. I think , I need to go in deep in both python & Django.

Comment: Hie Daniel, I found answer you gave to Irum here : [link] (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/jsq_mTdHurs). But I got this error TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'